# Trocar imagens por texto quando Navbar expande (e vice-versa)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com um problema. Trata-se de um menu responsivo que expande. Os elementos do menu são imagens de botões, que brilham quando o mouse passa por cima. Fiz isso usando *JS* e *Bootstrap*. Até aí, tudo bem.

O problema surge quando o menu vira o botão sanduíche e é clicado pra expandir. Eu queria que, dentro do menu expansivo, não aparecessem as imagens dos botões, mas sim um texto no lugar. E, quando o botão sanduíche sumisse e o menu voltasse a ser uma barra, as imagens dos botões voltassem a aparecer.

Aqui está o código da `Navbar`:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-2 offset-lg-1 order-lg-2 order-1">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                    <button class="navbar-toggler mt-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menubar">
                        <span class="fas fa-bars text-white"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menubar">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aeraer.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="aerhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="aerhvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-aer.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btaer"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-aer-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btaeron"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aerlogin.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="loginhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="loginhvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-login.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btlogin"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-login-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btloginon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aerplay.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="playhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="playhvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-play.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btplay"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-play-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btplayon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aerequipe.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="equipehvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="equipehvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-equipe.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btequipe"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-equipe-on.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btequipeon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aerrank.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="rankhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="rankhvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-rank.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btrank"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-rank-on.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btrankon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="aercontato.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="contatohvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="contatohvr(this,'off')">
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-contato.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btcontato"/>
                                    <img src="imagens/bt-contato-on.png" class="img-fluid btd"id="btcontatoon"/>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

Alguém teria alguma idéia de como posso tentar resolver isso?

Muito obrigado!

EDIT:
As pesquisas que fiz me trouxeram modos de trocar as imagens por textos, mas aí eles permaneciam como textos depois, não voltavam a ser imagens quando o menu virava barra novamente.

Vou upar uma imagem, pra deixar mais fácil de entender, caso meu texto esteja confuso.

[Imagem de Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NydIA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
let button = document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler');

button.addEventListener( 'click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    links.forEach(link => {
        link.classList.toggle('actived');
    });
});
```

```css
.nav-link > span {
    display: none;
}
.nav-link.actived > img {
    display: none;
}
.nav-link.actived > span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-2 offset-lg-1 order-lg-2 order-1">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler mt-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menubar">
                <span class="fas fa-bars text-white"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menubar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aeraer.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="aerhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="aerhvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-aer.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btaer"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-aer-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btaeron"/>
                            <span>Texto0</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerlogin.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="loginhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="loginhvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-login.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btlogin"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-login-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btloginon"/>
                            <span>Texto1</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerplay.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="playhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="playhvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-play.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btplay"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-play-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btplayon"/>
                            <span>Texto2</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerequipe.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="equipehvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="equipehvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-equipe.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btequipe"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-equipe-on.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btequipeon"/>
                            <span>Texto3</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerrank.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="rankhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="rankhvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-rank.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btrank"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-rank-on.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btrankon"/>
                            <span>Texto4</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aercontato.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="contatohvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="contatohvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-contato.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btcontato"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-contato-on.png" class="img-fluid btd"id="btcontatoon"/>
                            <span>Texto5</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eduardo, tua solução ficou quase perfeita. O único problema é que os botões não sumiram ao expandir. Agora, aparece os botões e o texto (a parte textual ficou perfeita).

Comment: Tu ja tem uma solução, acredito que esses detalhes podem ser realizados com ajustes em css ou mesmo até alterando ou adicionando novas classes de apoio em outras tags, que fazem o botão que diz que não quer que apareça, espero que isso ajude a buscar a solução que procura.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, o problema não é no css, é no JavaScript. Ao passar o mouse sobre o nav-link, ele ativa a function que faz a imagem brilhar, e aí ela aparece.

Comment: Pelo que vejo no seu código tem um evento ligado diretamente ao link <a> onmouseover="aerhvr(this,'on')" e o off

Comment: É esse evento que é responsavel pelo hover que é acionado quando passa o mouse, o que pode ser feito é remover o gatilho adicionado direto na tag <a> e fazer esse evento ser acionado exemplo quando a classe .onhover estiver junto a .nav-link, mas dai tu precisa alterar o jquery ou javascript criado para que fique dentro das condições que determinar

Comment: Vou tentar descobrir como fazer isso (sou iniciante ainda, tô engatinhando). Mas a tua resposta me deu um caminho pra seguir. Te agradeço muito.

Comment: Se remover da tag <a> o onmousehover vai ver que o efeito de quando passar o mouse vai sumir. Dai só veja a solução de como pode aplicar esse mesmo evento para quando realmente precisar e não como está, beleza.
Boa sorte

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas acho que seria assim, só não estilizei e não dei o hide quando o menu está em modo desktop, mas isso no css é simples

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 col-2 offset-lg-1 order-lg-2 order-1">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler mt-3" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menubar-text">
                <span class="fas fa-bars text-white"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menubar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aeraer.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="aerhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="aerhvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-aer.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btaer"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-aer-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btaeron"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerlogin.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="loginhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="loginhvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-login.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btlogin"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-login-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btloginon"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerplay.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="playhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="playhvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-play.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btplay"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-play-on.png" class="img-fluid btu" id="btplayon"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerequipe.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="equipehvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="equipehvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-equipe.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btequipe"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-equipe-on.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btequipeon"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerrank.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="rankhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="rankhvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-rank.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btrank"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-rank-on.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btrankon"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aercontato.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="contatohvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="contatohvr(this,'off')">
                            <img src="imagens/bt-contato.png" class="img-fluid btd" id="btcontato"/>
                            <img src="imagens/bt-contato-on.png" class="img-fluid btd"id="btcontatoon"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- MENU ONDE A IMAGEM VIRA TEXTO -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menubar-text">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aeraer.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="aerhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="aerhvr(this,'off')">
                            Texto 1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerlogin.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="loginhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="loginhvr(this,'off')">
                            Texto 2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerplay.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="playhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="playhvr(this,'off')">
                            Texto 3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerequipe.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="equipehvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="equipehvr(this,'off')">
                            Texto 4
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aerrank.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="rankhvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="rankhvr(this,'off')">
                            Texto 5
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="aercontato.html" class="nav-link" onmouseover="contatohvr(this,'on')" onmouseleave="contatohvr(this,'off')">
                            Texto 6
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

>